# Xcode - Access one view controller from multiple view controllers

Tags: xcode, view, controller

I have created an app which in total has 4 view controllers. 2 of these are pages that contain content with an (i) button in the top corner which links to an "about" section of the app. Currently I have 2 separate view controllers displaying the same thing (the about page) as I can't get the two view controllers to link to a single one when I click the button on each respectively. 
Is there a way for two view controllers to access one view controller without me having to create a different about page for each one?
Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

First you should set the button's target:

```
exampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside;
```

Then, in the button's method:

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
AboutViewController *aboutViewController = [[AboutViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Don't forget to add the about view controller's header file

```
#import "AboutViewController.h"
```

If you use storyboard, you should change the button's action method with

```
-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
[self.navigationController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aboutSegueIdentifier" sender:sender];
}
```